# tkinter radio buttons does not work inside function

Tags: python, function, radio-button, tkinter

I am trying to write a GUI (in fact a [PyMOL](http://www.pymol.org/) plugin) with radio buttons. I need the radio buttons to be inside a function.  I have two problems (if the radio buttons are outside a function I don´t have any problem):

1) the last two radio button looks gray and checked. (I think the correct behavior should be only one checked and none gray) setting a different default value (using ref_value.set()) does not change anything

2) I always get the default value ("1" in this example) when hit the submit button.

```
from Tkinter import *

def __init__(self):
    """this adds the Plugin to the PyMOL menu"""
    self.menuBar.addmenuitem('Plugin', 'command',
                        'Plugin name',
                        label = 'plugin',
                        command = lambda : draw_gui())

def draw_gui():
    global v
    master = Tk()
    master.title(' title ')
    Button(master, text='Submit', command=submit).pack(side=BOTTOM)
    v = StringVar()
    v.set(1)
    Radiobutton(master, text='option 1', variable=v, value=1).pack(side=LEFT)
    Radiobutton(master, text='option 2', variable=v, value=2).pack(side=LEFT)
    Radiobutton(master, text='option 3', variable=v, value=3).pack(side=LEFT)
    master.mainloop()


def submit():
    print v.get()
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should set the master explicitly, otherwise it will use the PyMOL GUI as master.

```
v = StringVar(master=master)
```

PS: thanks Thomas Holder for the answer.

Comment: Thank you! I know this is really old, but I was having the same issue and I was just about ready to throw my computer out the window - this solved the issue! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It works for me (I copied your code and added the lines `from Tkinter import *` and `if __name__ == "__main__": draw_gui()` which I assume you have too).  All the radio buttons work and I get 1, 2, 3 as appropriate in the output.

So if you are running the same code, there is a problem with the environment. I have Tkinter 73770 and Python 2.6.5 on Ubuntu 10.04 and am running the script from the command line.

Are you perhaps trying to run it from IDLE? That often doesn't play nice with other scripts that use Tkinter, because it is written in Tkinter itself.  If so, try running from the command line instead.

Comment: You are right the code works the way you say. I don´t have a `__name__ == "__main__": draw_gui()`. I am trying to write a PyMOl plugin [link](http://www.pymolwiki.org/index.php/Plugins_Tutorial) I am going to edit my question to add the whole code

Comment: In the new code, it looks like at least some of it is meant to be part of a `class` definition.  Could you post the shortest possible piece of code that compiles and runs by itself, but doesn't work as you expect?

Comment: I edit the code and now is the shortest possible code. 
The function `__init__(self)` is necessary to load the code as a PyMOL Plugin. I follow the instructions in this [tutorial](http://www.pymolwiki.org/index.php/Plugins_Tutorial). If I omit this function and instead I add the line `if __name__ == "__main__": draw_gui()` I am able to run the code from a terminal and It works as expected.